# Tomcat output start page only on 80 port Centos7

Tags: tomcat, port, centos7, firewall, tomcat9

I installed ApacheTomcat 9 on my Centos7 server, started it and if i tryed to open localhost:8080 page not open. If I change `Connector port` to 80 in `/conf/server.xml` it working. What I need to do that Tomcat worked 8080 port or other.

I installed firewalld and tryed these commands:

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent`

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent`

`firewall-cmd --reload`

`firewall-cmd --list-ports`
its output: 8080/tcp 80/tcp

`iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Tomcat Server port"`

Connect part in server.xml

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the connector part of your server.xml?
Port 80 is (normally) the standard httpd production port, Tomcat uses by default 8080
depending on the user who runs tomcat, you can't run low ports (1-1024) as non-root.
Without your sever.xml it's just guessing around ;)

Comment: I updated my question, this problem not only with Tomcat, I have the same issue with Jenkins: it's can't work on 8080 or other port but if I run it on 80, it's working fine

Comment: Your redirectPort=8443
Try http://localhost:8443 on the server. If not installed, use LYNX by updating the cache and installing it with 'sudo yum install lynx'
then call lynx http:localhost:8443 and all other suggested ports (80, 8080)

Comment: I tryed  lynx localhost:80. Only response 80 port. 8080 and 8443 - page not found